# Change millisec for window.setInterval function

Tags: javascript

I used `window.setInterval` function. this function includes 3 arguments :

```
setInterval(code,millisec,lang)
```

I used that like this:

```
var counter = 1;
window.setInterval(function() {}, 1000 * ++counter);
```

but when first time set timer (second argument), is not changed and that act Like below code:

```
window.setInterval(function() {}, 1000);
```

please write correct code for change timer

Comment: What is `millisec`? A variable?

Comment: user667429, please, clarify your question. What do you want?

Comment: that is timer for window.setInterval

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to change the interval time each time the function is fired. The setInterval doesn't work this way and the interval deleay remains the same for the liftime of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.setTimeout` instead.

```
var delay = 1000;
function myTimer() {
    // do whatever

    window.setTimeout(myTimer, delay);
}

window.setTimeout(myTimer, delay);
```

You can manipulate `delay` in the body of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that javascript first execute '1000 * ++counter' once and then do not update the time interval.
You should try to use a timeout instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout 
And create a new time out with the new value every time your time out function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're after is not `setInterval` but rather `setTimeout` in a loop:

```
var counter = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert("#" + counter);
        counter++;
    }, i * 1000);
}
```

This will execute three different "timers" one after the other.
Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/86DRd/